# How to process JSON using jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I have a controller that returns a list of custom linq-to-sql model objects in JSON format to jquery ajax calls:

```
List<MyAppLibrary.Model.Search> listSearches = search.ToList();
        return new JsonResult { Data = listSearches };
```

I have the following javascript which gets the response:

```
$.getJSON("/ajax/getbrands",
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

I'd like to know how I can process that data response in javascript? How do I get the Name paramter of the Model.Search object?

Thanks.

Comment: If  you can show the json returned by method it will be of immense help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `data` variable that gets returned from the jQuery AJAX call contains the JSON object.  You can access the fields of each of your `MyAppLibrary.Model.Search` objects in your JavaScript like so:

```
// this will grab the Search object at index 0 of your list
// and put the Name property's value of the Search object
// into a var
var firstItemName = data.Data[0].Name;
```

Answer (score 6):

The `data` argument will have a `Data` property, which is your list of `Search` models.

```
 $.getJSON("/ajax/getbrands",
        function(data) {
             $.each(data.Data, function(i, item) {
                  // ... item will be a Search model...
                  // ... i will be the index of the item in the list...
                  // ...
             });
        }
 );
```

Comment: I used this format, but had to change the each line to 
$.each(data, function(i,item){
for it to work.  Interestingly the jquery site says to use
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
but that didn't work for me with jquery.1.3.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jquery.json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) plugin play with the JSON returned.